# Showing custom validation error in bootstrap style

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want show input error in style of boostrap. 
[bootstrap error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmtzq.png)
But when I use this code

```
let $emailContainer = $('[data-coffee-role="email-container"]');
$emailContainer.validate().showErrors({'email':'Email already exists'});
```

I error shows in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQoU.png) way. How i can show my error in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmtzq.png) way?

Html

```html
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form data-coffee-order="coffee">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="coffeeOrder">Coffee order</label>
                    <input id="coffeeOrder" type="text" class="form-control" name="coffee" autofocus required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" data-coffee-role="email-container">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Reset</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
 FormHandler.prototype.addHandler = function(fn, check){
        this.$formElement.on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const data = {};
            $(this).serializeArray().forEach(item => data[item.name] = item.value);
            if(check(data.email)){
                let $emailContainer = $('[data-coffee-role="email-container"]');
                $emailContainer.validate().showErrors({'email':'Email already exists'});
                return;
            }
            fn(data);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @S.Orioli I'm using 4.3.1

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? the `HTML` for example. Btw seems like your are missing some bootstrap class

Comment: @S.Orioli updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you messed up with external libraries you're using. The behaviour your're looking for is a simple `HTML` form validation, that can be achived even without using `boostrap`.

The graphical aspect of the message depends on the browser your're using:

[image: html form validation error on different browsers]

If you want to extend default message text or create custom validators, this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) can help you.

Check this simple example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
        <h1>Form validation demo</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-4 form-group'>
                <label for="name">First Name:</label>
                <input id="fname" class="form-control" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4 form-group'>
                <label for="name">Last Name:</label>
                <input id="lname" class="form-control" min="3" required>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4 form-group'>
                <label for="name">Email address:</label>
                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```